# How To Access Class Properties From A Base Abstract Class

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to design a base abstract class that can gather all the properties from classes that are inherited from it.  I'm getting the name fine, but getting the value is not working.  I get the  runtime error "Object does not match target".  Any help is much appreciated.

```cs
public string Get()
{
    string ret = "";
    var type = GetType();
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in this.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        ret += p.Name + "`" + p.GetValue(type) + "~";
        //i've also tried
        //ret += p.Name + "`" + p.GetValue(this) + "~";
    }

    ret = ret.TrimEnd('~');
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: `p.GetValue(type)` should be `p.GetValue(this)` - read the documentation for `PropertyInfo.GetValue` carefully.

Comment: Yes.  I've tried that to. Parameter count mismatch.

Comment: *Which* method did you try? [PropertyInfoGetValue(Object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=net-7.0#system-reflection-propertyinfo-getvalue(system-object)) only needs 1 argument - the object to read from

Comment: Your code passes exactly 1 parameter, are you sure you have tired  exactly this?

Comment: I edited it up above.   oreach (PropertyInfo p in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
             ret += p.Name + "`" + p.GetValue(type) + "~";
            //i've also tried
            //ret += p.Name + "`" + p.GetValue(this) + "~";
        }

Comment: Post the *actual* code that didn't work. I get no compilation errors with `p.GetValue(this)`

Comment: What's the actual error you got? Was it a compilation or a runtime error? A compilation error means you tried to call the wrong method. A *runtime* error means the parameter getter has parameters itself. That happens with indexer parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Parameter count mismatch.

It seems that one of the properties is an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/), you can ignore such properties by checking [`GetIndexParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getindexparameters?view=net-7.0) on the `PropertyInfo` (or process it accordingly if needed):

```cs
if (!p.GetIndexParameters().Any())
{
    ret += p.Name + "`" + p.GetValue(this) + "~";
}
```

Demo with the runtime exception [@sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

Comment: I think it should be stressed that indexers produce a *runtime* error. The way the OP's question/comments were written, it sounded like there was a compile error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the object you want to get property values from

`p.GetValue(this)`

Comment: Yes.  I've tried that to.  Parameter count mismatch.

Comment: @JBryanB are you sure? This code works fine. Post the actual code that failed

Answer (score 1):

When working with *arbitrary* classes, we should take into account, that we can have

- `static` properties: `public static int MyId => 3;`
- **Indexers** `public int this[int index] { get => index;}`
- **Write only** properties `public int MyId {set => m_Id = value;}`

So far so good, let's *query* the properties:

```
using System.Linq;

...

public string Get() => string.Join("~", GetType()
  .GetProperties()
  .Where(prop => prop.CanRead)                            // readable
  .Where(prop => !prop.GetGetMethod().IsStatic)           // instance  
  .Where(prop => prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)   // not an indexer
  .Select(prop => $"{prop.Name} `{prop.GetValue(this)}"));
```

Another issue is *string manipulations*: if you have a lot of properties (long `ret`) adding strings can be *slow*. If you want to *join* strings, just put `string.Join`.